# How to convert View into Bitmap without loss the quality "resolution"

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-bitmap

## Hi guys,

i'm trying to get  bitmap from a custom view, but i get bitmap with low quality?

#### i need High quality bitmap.

```
static Bitmap createTextWidgetImage(Context context, int widgetID) {
        WidgetTextView widgetTextView = new WidgetTextView(context);
        widgetTextView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bundle bundle = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetOptions(widgetID);
        int minHeight = bundle.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);
        int minWidth = bundle.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH);
        widgetTextView.measure(minWidth, minHeight);
        widgetTextView.layout(0, 0, minWidth, minHeight);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(minWidth, minHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        widgetTextView.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: You will get whatever `WidgetTextView` draws to the `Canvas`, for whatever size you elected to use for the `Canvas`. If you do not like what `WidgetTextView` is drawing to the `Canvas`, fix your drawing code, or possibly fix the `Canvas` (e.g., perhaps your size is too small).

Comment: Thanks it was helpful answer.